# how to define Django settings without default DB settings?

Tags: django

According to Django Docs we can define empty django settings  like this {} but it still raises error .

ImproperlyConfigured at /
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

```
"""
Django settings for impactFund project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))[0]


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 's^(gvcg1_!!!8wnpikp[hj4+%ypay1$zsf54=j6o3cuuxigjxiscqno'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'Ken_app',
    'app',

    'captcha',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'treebeard',
    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',    
    'cms',  # django CMS itself
    'mptt',  # utilities for implementing a modified pre-order traversal tree
    'menus',  # helper for model independent hierarchical website navigation
    #'south',  # intelligent schema and data migrations
    'sekizai',  # for javascript and css management
    'djangocms_admin_style',  # for the admin skin. You **must** add 'djangocms_admin_style' in the list **before** 'django.contrib.admin'.
     # to enable messages framework (see :ref:`Enable messages <enable-messages>`)

)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',

    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',    

)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Fundimpact.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Fundimpact.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases


DATABASES = {

    'default': {  # Leave this blank, we do not want a 'default' database defined.
        'ENGINE': '', 
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },


    'prisen_db':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'prisen_db',                      
        'USER': 'prmken_user',                      
        'HOST': '59.77.142', 
        'PASSWORD':'PmN7&#5B',    

    },
    'prism_db':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'prism_db',                      
        'USER': 'prism_user',                      
        'HOST': '59.77.142', 
        'PASSWORD':'PC$MN',    

    }
 }   



DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['app.dbRouter.AppDBRouter', 'Ken_app.dbRouter.Ken_appDBRouter']

TEMPLATES = [
   {
       'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
       'DIRS': [
       os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'Ken_app','template'),
       os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'app','templates'),
                ],
       'APP_DIRS': True,
       'OPTIONS': {
           'context_processors': [
               'django.template.context_processors.debug',
               'django.template.context_processors.request',
               'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
               'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
               'django.core.context_processors.i18n',              
               'django.core.context_processors.static',
               'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
           ],
       },
   },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

#FILE_CHARSET = ""

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)



CKEDITOR_SETTINGS = {
    'language': '{{ language }}',
    'toolbar': 'CMS',
    'skin': 'moono',
}


CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
    'content': {
        'plugins': ['TextPlugin', 'LinkPlugin'],
        'default_plugins':[
            {
                'plugin_type':'TextPlugin',
                'values':{
                    'body':'<p>Great websites : %(_tag_child_1)s and %(_tag_child_2)s</p>'
                },
                'children':[
                    {
                        'plugin_type':'LinkPlugin',
                        'values':{
                            'name':'django',
                            'url':'https://www.djangoproject.com/'
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        'plugin_type':'LinkPlugin',
                        'values':{
                            'name':'django-cms',
                            'url':'https://www.django-cms.org'
                        },
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

these are my routers for both apps which are in individual app folders

```
import random

class Ken_appDBRouter(object):
    """
    A router to control app db operations
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        "Point all operations on app models to 'kenya"
        from django.conf import settings
        if not settings.DATABASES.has_key('Ken_app'):
            return None
        if model._meta.app_label == 'Ken_app':
            return 'prisen_db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        "Point all operations on app1 models to 'kenya'"
        from django.conf import settings
        if not settings.DATABASES.has_key('Ken_app'):
            return None
        if model._meta.app_label == 'Ken_app':
            return 'prisen_db'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        "Allow any relation if a model in app is involved"
        from django.conf import settings
        if not settings.DATABASES.has_key('Ken_app'):
            return None
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'Ken_app' or obj2._meta.app_label == 'Ken_app':
            return True
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        "Make sure the Ken_app app only appears on the 'kenya' db"
        from django.conf import settings
        if not settings.DATABASES.has_key('Ken_app'):
            return None
        if db == 'prisen_db':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'Ken_app'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'Ken_app':
            return False
        return None


import random

class AppDBRouter(object):
    """
    A router to control app db operations
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        "Point all operations on app models to 'app'"
        from django.conf import settings
        if not settings.DATABASES.has_key('app'):
            return None
        if model._meta.app_label == 'app':
            return 'prism_db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        "Point all operations on app1 models to 'india'"
        from django.conf import settings
        if not settings.DATABASES.has_key('app'):
            return None
        if model._meta.app_label == 'app':
            return 'prism_db'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        "Allow any relation if a model in app is involved"
        from django.conf import settings
        if not settings.DATABASES.has_key('app'):
            return None
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'app' or obj2._meta.app_label == 'app':
            return True
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        "Make sure the app app only appears on the 'app' db"
        from django.conf import settings
        if not settings.DATABASES.has_key('app'):
            return None
        if db == 'prism_db':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'app'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'app':
            return False
        return None
```

here is the trace back. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEv9T.png)

Comment: Care to tell us what the error is?..

Comment: And we're supposed to magically find out what the error is with our psychic powers. But I need a headache first, thank you.

Comment: ImproperlyConfigured at /
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

Comment: This error happens when you _use_ the default (empty) backend, not when you define it. Please provide the full traceback and the relevant code.

Comment: But when I use default : {} raises same error , I can't remove default as it has to be there even when not used .

Comment: The error is not in your configuration. The error is that your code is **executing a query on the default database** when it is defined as empty. So as I said, please provide the full traceback and the relevant code that is executing that query.

Comment: here you go  attached

Answer (score 2):

Your `default` database is not empty:

```
'default': {  # Leave this blank, we do not want a 'default' database defined.
    'ENGINE': '', 
    'NAME': '',
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '',
},
```

Change it to

```
'default': {},
```

Additionally, you are missing routing for `auth`. Change one of your routers to accept also `auth` or add a third router for it.

Comment: The error is ImproperlyConfigured at /
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with db routing, but it seems you are missing routing for the `auth` app. For `auth` both of your routers seem to return None, in which case Django reverts back to `default`.

Comment: I guess you found it in Docs where routers were defined for same application where auth tables will go to auth_db and rest to replicas(db)  but in my case I have 2 different apps and 2 different databases in 1 project .

Comment: It doesn't matter. `auth` is an app the same as your own two apps, and it also needs a database. So you need to modify one of your routers to accept also `auth` or add a third router for it.

Comment: Do you mean like auth is a predefined class which routes all authentication related tables , cause this way I need to have 4 routers 2 for non auth related , 2 for auth related

Comment: `auth` is a default app provided by Django, that takes care of user management (see the second entry under `INSTALLED_APPLICATIONS`). There's only one `auth` per project, so you should only need one more.

Comment: then this file should be in project folder ?

Comment: Sorry, which file? You don't need to add any more files. You only need to add routing for the `auth` -app. Or add the `default` setting to your database configuration, which would then be used by `auth`.

Comment: In Docs we have a class called [AuthRouter(object)](http://https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/)  if you are refering to that then we need a file to put those functions under them . And then we can add AuthRouters to DB routers [] in settings file.

Comment: The router definition includes the path to the router. I suggest you put it in the same directory with your settings.py, as it isn't specific to any of your own apps. But an easier solution would be to use the `default` DB configuration for `auth`.

Comment: How to use the default DB configuration for auth

Comment: Simply populate the `default` -section in `DATABASES`.

Comment: So I need to add one more DB for auth ?

Comment: Yes. Alternatively you can change one of your existing routers to accept also auth.

Comment: Even when I do that project runs but it only chooses default database not others

Comment: I guess routers are not working properly don't know why

Answer (score 0):

To surpass the internal checking mechanism :

```
# We wont use Django databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': '',
    }
}

# Override TestRunner methods
TEST_RUNNER = 'tests.NoSQLTestRunner'
```

You will make another tests.py file and save the things below

```
from django.test.simple import DjangoTestSuiteRunner
from django.test import TestCase

class NoSQLTestRunner(DjangoTestSuiteRunner):
    def setup_databases(self):
        pass
    def teardown_databases(self, *args):
        pass

class NoSQLTestCase(TestCase):
    def _fixture_setup(self):
        pass
    def _fixture_teardown(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Since I have multiple apps , where do i need to add this file ?

Comment: this file will be in the same folder as the settings one